# Simple password-prompt in C

Tags: c, pointers, fgets, password-prompt

I'm trying to make a simple user and password autentication in C.
I was told to never use gets() when getting input and I should use fgets() instead.
But I'm not sure of how the fgets() works or why is giving me this input.
Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int login(char *user, char *passwd){

    int enter = 0;
    char p[6];
    char u[6];
    printf("User: ");
    fgets(u, sizeof u, stdin);
    printf("Pass: "); 
    fgets(p, sizeof p, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    if (strcmp(user, u) == 0 && strcmp(passwd, p) == 0){
        enter = 1;
    }
    return entrar;
}

int main(){
    char user[] = "admin";
    char passwd[] = "12345";
    if (login(user, passwd)){
        puts("--ACCESS GRANTED--");
    }
    else{
        puts("--Wrong pass or user--");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ouput

> User: admin
>
> Pass:
>
> --Wrong pass or user--

It doesn't even let me enter the password after I press enter.

Comment: 'Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.'.  Stop bean-counting.  If you are going to need text line buffers, just declare [128], (unless short of RAM).  Trying to exact-size buffers will just get you bugs, input calls returning early, newline chars left in input streams, that kind of stuff..

Comment: What happens if you have a system("PAUSE") or a getch() inbetween the fgets()? I would guess that since the password is being skipped, once you hit enter it's consuming the line and using it for both the u[] and p[] array.

Comment: bear in mind: (1) fgets stores `\n` in the output buffer,  (2) if the whole input line doesn't fit in the output buffer, the next `fgets` call will read more from the same line, therefore it will not wait

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the size of your char[], if you set it to 6, 'admin' will overflow, as reading with gets will read some extra characters.

Try with a bigger string, I'm sure you can afford it, say:

```
char u[10];
char p[10];
```

And that is still a quite stingy ;)

Answer (score 0):

well.. you had two problems
one as suggested here, you should change the size of u and p to 10, the other is, the `fgets` also fetches the new line `\n` that you need to remove before comparing the strings.

so the complete answer would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int login(char *user, char *passwd){

    int enter = 0;
    char p[10];
    char u[10];
    char *pos;
    printf("User: ");
    fgets(u, sizeof u, stdin);
    if ((pos=strchr(u, '\n')) != NULL) {
        *pos = '\0';
    }
    printf("'%s'\n", u);
    printf("Pass: "); 
    fgets(p, sizeof p, stdin);
    if ((pos=strchr(p, '\n')) != NULL) {
        *pos = '\0';
    }
    printf("'%s'\n", p);
    if (strcmp(user, u) == 0 && strcmp(passwd, p) == 0){
        enter = 1;
    }
    return enter;
}

int main(){
    char user[] = "admin";
    char passwd[] = "12345";
    if (login(user, passwd)){
        puts("--ACCESS GRANTED--");
    }
    else{
        puts("--Wrong pass or user--");
    }
    return 0;
}
```